# jQuery - Image replacement animation (toggle)

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:-

**HTML**

```
<div class="mobile-menu"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.mobile-menu {
    background: url(../img/buttons/menu-01.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 7px 0;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.mobile-menu').click(function(event){

    var index = 0;
    var imagesArray = ["http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk//wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/buttons/menu-01.png", 
                       "http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk//wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/buttons/menu-02.png",
                       "http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk//wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/buttons/menu-03.png", 
                       "http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk//wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/buttons/menu-04.png", 
                       "http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk//wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/buttons/menu-05.png", 
                       "http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk//wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/buttons/menu-06.png", 
                       "http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk//wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/buttons/menu-07.png"];
    var background1 = $(".mobile-menu");
    var background2 = $(".mobile-menu");

    //Set the starting background
    background2.css("background","url('"+ imagesArray[index] +"')");
    interval = setInterval(changeImage,30);
    interval;

    function changeImage(){

        background2.css("background","url('"+ imagesArray[index] +"')");

        //Hide the top element which we will load the "new" background in now
        background1.fadeOut(10);

        index++;

        if(index == 6) {
            clearInterval(interval); // stop the interval
        }
        if(index >= imagesArray.length){
            index = 0;
        }

        //Set the background of the top element to the new background
        background1.css("background","url('"+ imagesArray[index] +"')");
        //Fade in the top element
        background1.fadeIn(10);
    }

});
```

Basically this animates how I want between the 7 different images. On the next click the cycle needs to go the other way round, so it will load menu-07 through to menu-01 (so some sort of toggle to run the opposite of this function).

How can I achieve this?

[SEE JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/7m3ob5m9/1/)

Comment: are you  sure your fiddle is working?

Comment: @Reddy yeah I just tried it?

Comment: It's just a grey arrow which goes from pointing downwards to pointing upwards on click, needs to do the opposite on second click, essentially toggling between the two on each click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unusefull the setInterval function because the fadeIn / fadeOut have already a time and oncomplete callback.

My proposal to preload imaages and animate in up or down direction the images is:

```js
var imagesArray = ["http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/buttons/menu-01.png",
                   "http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/buttons/menu-02.png",
                   "http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/buttons/menu-03.png",
                   "http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/buttons/menu-04.png",
                   "http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/buttons/menu-05.png",
                   "http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/buttons/menu-06.png",
                   "http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/buttons/menu-07.png"];




function preloadImg(pictureUrls, callback) {
  var i, j, loaded = 0;
  var imagesArray = [];

  for (i = 0, j = pictureUrls.length; i < j; i++) {
    imagesArray.push(new Image());
  }
  for (i = 0, j = pictureUrls.length; i < j; i++) {
    (function (img, src) {
      img.onload = function () {
        if (++loaded == pictureUrls.length && callback) {
          callback(imagesArray);
        }
      };
      img.src = src;
    }(imagesArray[i], pictureUrls[i]));
  }
};


function changeImage(background, imagesArray, index, reverse) {
  background.css("background-image", "url('" + imagesArray[index].src + "')").fadeIn(10, function() {
    if (reverse) {
      index--;
      if (index == -1) {
        return; // stop the interval
      }
    } else {
      index++;
      if (index == imagesArray.length) {
        return; // stop the interval
      }
    }
    //Fade in the top element
    background.fadeOut(10, function () {
      //Set the background of the top element to the new background
      background.css("background-image", "url('" + imagesArray[index] + "')");
      changeImage(background, imagesArray, index, reverse);
    });
  });
}



$(function () {
  /* Preload Image */
  preloadImg(imagesArray, function (imagesArray) {
    $(".mobile-menu").css("background-image", "url('" + imagesArray[0].src + "')")
    $('.mobile-menu').on('click', {imgs: imagesArray}, function (event) {
      var background = $(".mobile-menu");
      var bi = background.css('background-image');
      var index = 0;
      var reverse = false;
      if (imagesArray[0].src != bi.replace('url("', '').replace('")', '')) {
        index = imagesArray.length - 1;
        reverse = true;
      }
      changeImage(background, event.data.imgs, index, reverse);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.mobile-menu {
  background: url(http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/buttons/menu-01.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 7px 0;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  transition-duration: 0.8s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="mobile-menu"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lock at this: [your jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7m3ob5m9/2/) I made a new function that reverses the array when needed.

```js
/* Preload Image */
var reverse = false;

function myArray(reverse) {
  var imagesArray = ["http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/buttons/menu-01.png",
    "http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/buttons/menu-02.png",
    "http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/buttons/menu-03.png",
    "http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/buttons/menu-04.png",
    "http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/buttons/menu-05.png",
    "http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/buttons/menu-06.png",
    "http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/buttons/menu-07.png"
  ];

  if (reverse) {
    imagesArray.reverse();
  }
  
  return imagesArray
}


$('.mobile-menu').click(function(event) {
  var imagesArray = myArray(reverse); 
  var index = 0;

  var background1 = $(".mobile-menu");
  var background2 = $(".mobile-menu");

  //Set the starting background
  background2.css("background", "url('" + imagesArray[index] + "')");
  interval = setInterval(changeImage, 30);
  interval;

  function changeImage() {

    background2.css("background", "url('" + imagesArray[index] + "')");

    //Hide the top element which we will load the "new" background in now
    background1.fadeOut(10);

    index++;

    if (index == 6) {
      clearInterval(interval); // stop the interval
    }
    if (index >= imagesArray.length) {
      index = 0;
    }

    //Set the background of the top element to the new background
    background1.css("background", "url('" + imagesArray[index] + "')");
    //Fade in the top element
    background1.fadeIn(10);


  }

  if(!reverse) {
     reverse = true;
    } else {
     reverse = false;
    }

});
```

```css
.mobile-menu {
  background: url(http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/buttons/menu-01.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 7px 0;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  transition-duration: 0.8s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mobile-menu"></div>
```

Comment: Many thanks @Zorken17 - I've just noticed if you click it repeatedly quickly it starts an infinite loop, is there a way to prevent this?